# How to apply style to all SeekBars below and above API 21?

Tags: android, android-layout, styles, android-styles, android-seekbar

I need to apply a style in styles.xml to all SeekBar views in my XML layouts, so I tried this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="seekBarStyle">@style/SeekBar</item>
</style>

<style name="SeekBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/button_color</item> <!-- below api 21 it's necessary this line and to add this style with android:theme in the layout xml file -->

    <item name="android:progressBackgroundTint">@color/button_color</item>
    <item name="android:thumbTint">@color/button_color</item>
    <item name="android:thumbTintMode">src_in</item>
    <item name="android:progressTint">@color/button_color</item>
</style>
```

The problem is that it works only in devices above api 21. For example in a device with API 19 Kitkat doesn't work.

The only way to make it work is to forze this line in each SeekBar in all the XML layouts: `android:theme="@style/SeekBar"`, and that is not a correct way to do it.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the Material theme attributes(like `android:colorAccent, android:colorPrimary or android:colorPrimaryDark` etc) are intended to work with Android 21, and if you want to use those in API Level before 21, 
you add `<item name=”colorPrimary”>@color/my_awesome_color</item>`
in `values/themes.xml`, after adding AppCompact dependencies, in your `build.gradle`,

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"
}
```

You can read about this more at the [this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) blog post